# AutoComplete feature output using javascript/python

Tags: javascript, python

Could anyone can help me on the below scenario. I cannot understand how to store an validate the response of suggestions;

A search input box on item search web page has an autocomplete feature. It uses external autocomplete service which has a REST interface with JSON response. 
Assume appropriate REST interface and JSON response for autocomplete service  Script should validate if returned response is really a valid response - for example for input string “AS” make sure that all returned strings are starting with “AS”, etc. Script should also print the input query string and output autocomplete strings on the screen.

Comment: What have you tried? How are the strings you want to autocomplete stored? Where are they stored? etc.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackexchange! Could you please clarify in your question exactly what the problem is? Do you have an interface that you're programming against and code that you've tried? It's much easier for us to help if there's more context here.